# How can I restore the hardware state after pigpio wave output?

Tags: pigpio

The following example program sends a short pulse on GPIO 14 using *pigpio*.

```py
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi() # connect to Pi

pi.wave_add_new()
pi.set_mode(14, pigpio.OUTPUT)

wf=[]
wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1 << 14, 0, 500))
wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1 << 14, 800))

pi.wave_clear()
pi.wave_add_generic(wf)
wid = pi.wave_create()
pi.wave_send_once(wid)

while pi.wave_tx_busy():
  pass

pi.wave_clear()
pi.stop()
```

It is run with *pigpiod* executed with these parameters in an attempt to minimize its interference with audio: `pigpiod -l -m -t 0 -x 16384`

Yet, even after terminating *pigpiod*, the sound from IQaudio sounds garbled: played intermittently at a high speed with *vlc* or sounding like white noise with *speaker_test*. Killing and rerunning *pigpiod* doesn't help. Only a reboot fixes the problem. Running *pigpiod* without running the program, or configuring *pigpio* without using its wave functionality doesn't create a problem.

Any ideas on how to restore the hardware's state after the wave output so that IQaudio sound works correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way provided by pigpio.

pigpio takes over the PWM and PCM clocks when you use waves. There is no provision made by pigpio to restore the clocks to the previous state.

Comment: Thank you! (And thank you for developing pigpio.) So the solution would be to modify pigpio to restore the clocks. I'm moving this to a pigpio issue https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/issues/567

Answer (score 0):

The hardware PWM continues to run once it is set and the appropriate registers which control PWM & Clock can only be accessed by code with root access.
(I have never used PCM but the same would apply.)

It would be possible to write code which changes clocks but "restore" is more problematic as there is no default. Normally these are set (presumably by kernel) to a value to suit analog audio.

You could take a snapshot of the appropriate registers & restore values.

I know of no code to do this (other than the few libraries which support hardware PWM).

See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2067934#p2067934 - this means the PWM Device Tree overlay is effectively useless as there is no support for setting clocks.